# Can I change the default input format of the HTML color input in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

In Chrome 83, the color picker that appears upon clicking a `<input type="color">` widget defaults to RGB input:

[image: Chrome color picker using RGB input]

The input format can be changed to HSL or HEX by clicking the two little arrows to the right of the letter "B".

Is there a way that I can change the default input format from RGB to HEX, or to only allow HEX input? HTML/CSS/JS would be ideal, but I'd be curious if there's even a Chrome setting to adjust this.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible (as of December 2020). You could implement and provide a color picker with JavaScript.

Each browser (or OS combination) will show a default color picker or the OS's color picker.

https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/09/14/hsl-color-selector-using-html5-and-css shows a different approach: a range slider with a gradient as background. It does not work in all browsers, but it might fit your requirements.

```css
.spectrum {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 7px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsl(0, 100%, 50%), hsl(60, 100%, 50%), hsl(120, 100%, 50%), hsl(180, 100%, 50%), hsl(240, 100%, 50%), hsl(300, 100%, 50%) 100%);
}

input[type=range] {
  width: 161px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="spectrum"></span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="300" step="1">
```